# AR Tools based on location based and hand gestures

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to know what AR "SDK" tools are based on location based and support hand gesture for android

Comment: You question is not clear. Do you mean you want AR SDKs that are only location based, and not marker based like Vuforia? And you want to support hand gestures but not cardboard?

Comment: @yakobom yes, sorry if my question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you will need to combine two different tools.
For location based, you can check [mixare](http://www.mixare.org/), which is also open source. You can also look at this list of AR tools [here](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks), and check the ones that are marked with 'GPS'. It is a little long, and not 100% accurate, but it gathers a lot of usefull information.

For hand gestures, it really depends what you need - there are various approaches, such that requires some heavy programming with an image processing library like OpenCV, and others. Here are two examples, you can start from these and then consider how to progress:
[HandWave](https://github.com/kritts/HandWave),  [HandGestureApp](https://github.com/eaglesky/HandGestureApp)

Comment: Thanks for your help